# How to link against frameworks that are not in the standard location?

Tags: macos, rust

I tried to link against a private framework in `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks` using

```
#[link(name = "MultitouchSupport", kind = "framework")]
```

But the linker tells me that the MultitouchSupport framework was not found. I also tried

```
#[link(name = "/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MultitouchSupport", kind = "framework")]
```

and

```
#[link(name = "/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MultitouchSupport.framework", kind = "framework")]
```

with the file extension, but neither work.

Is it even possible to link against frameworks that are not in the standard location of `/System/Library/Frameworks`?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `osx` framework, but have you tried to add `println!("cargo:rustc-link-search=native={}", some_dir);` in your `build.rs`?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I also thought that the build script might be the right place to solve the problem, but unfortunately the linker seems to ignore the println statements in the build rs. I checked that build.rs is actually executed and that the output is: "cargo:rustc-link-search=native=/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks". I also tried a version with a tailing "/"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out that WiSaGaN's suggestion was quite close to the solution: It works if you use search=framework in the build.rs.
The solution was to use the following build.rs:

```
fn main()
{
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-search=framework={}", "/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks");
}
```

Thank you, WiSaGaN!

Using this build.rs you can link as usual:

```
#[link(name = "MultitouchSupport", kind = "framework")]
```